why does -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 have no effect on functions called by C++ stdlib functions
At work, some of the binaries are required to be compiled with -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2. While verifying the compiled binary with checksec or hardening-check, I found that not all fortifiable functions were protected. Upon further investigation, I discovered that all the unprotected functions were called by C++ stdlib functions, not directly by the application code. I think it's maybe because stdlib implementations are considered safe thus no protection is needed. I want to know which of the following is true:

Stdlib functions are treated specially so _FORTIFY_SOURCE is not applied
Some general rules optimize protection away and happen to apply to stdlib
I'm missing something. If so, what exactly am I missing?

Example:
foo.cpp
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

std::vector<float> foo() {
    std::mt19937 rng;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> dis(-1.0f, 1.0f);
    auto generator = std::bind(dis, rng);
    std::vector<float> vec(10);
    std::generate_n(vec.begin(), vec.size(), generator);
    return vec;
}

Executing the following commands:
g++ -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -shared -fPIC foo.cpp -o libfoo.so
checksec --fortify-file=libfoo.so

yields the following output:
* FORTIFY_SOURCE support available (libc)    : Yes
* Binary compiled with FORTIFY_SOURCE support: No

 ------ EXECUTABLE-FILE ------- . -------- LIBC --------
 Fortifiable library functions | Checked function names
 -------------------------------------------------------
 memcpy                         | __memcpy_chk

SUMMARY:

* Number of checked functions in libc                : 79
* Total number of library functions in the executable: 38
* Number of Fortifiable functions in the executable : 1
* Number of checked functions in the executable      : 0
* Number of unchecked functions in the executable    : 1

which shows that the binary was not compiled with FORTIFY_SOURCE support and memcpy was not checked, even though -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 was used while compiling the library.

Related (if not duplicates): why does -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 has no effect in my compilation? and D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 flag usage not gets effect, and many more.
